# Script should run by own during server startup

Tags: linux, shell, unix

We are using JON tool to monitor our infrastructure .we set up the threshold for RAM usage(60%,65% of total RAM)using tool GUI.

In case if server(which is in in cloud ) RAM size is increased we need to manually change the threshold level using GUI .To avoid that I wrote a shell script which uses JON CLI to update the threshold of RAM (based on current RAM size), script is working and no problem in that.

For example, initially if RAM size is 8 gb we set up the threshold (65% from 8gb) based on current size. Due to some need if they increase the size to 16 GB we need to set up the threshold(65% from 16GB) manually.To avoid that I created shell script which uses JON CLI. to update threshold value( during maintenance they shut down the servers and increase the RAM size as per their need.)

Problem:

If the server size is increased I need to run the script manually to set the threshold. Since they are bringing the server to down during size changes , the script need to run by own once they started the server. So I placed my script in /etc/rc.local file Recently the team has increased the RAM size and started the server but there is no change in threshold (which means script doesn't run by own). Thus i ran the script manually to update the threshold

Expectation:

Script should run by own during server start up.

Flavour:centos(6.5)

Even though it is basic thing please guide and help on this.

Comment: I do not really know the centos Linux flavor, but the `/etc/rc.local` script should run at startup time in almost if not all Unix-like systems. But it may not have the expected environment (PATH, etc.). IMHO you should twice control all environment variables, and have you script to have a visible effect in its first executable line to make sure whether it was called (something like `/bin/date > /test_script.log`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly,
you script does not start from /etc/rc.local.

Please check, if /etc/rc.local is executed.
For that add something like:

```
touch /tmp/created-by-rc.local
```

to it and restart the server.

After that you will know, if /etc/rc.local is started
and depending on that you can go further this or that way.

Also, you can create an own start script for your script.
Check this article, where the procedure is described in details:

https://techarena51.com/index.php/how-to-create-an-init-script-on-centos-6/